# Back inclined Italics Font

Tags: fonts

Do we have any back inclined Italics Font? Just the opposite of the forward inclined Italics?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you absolutely want to use something like this and you can use XeTeX or LuaTeX to compile your document, you can fake it for any font you like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\fontspec[FakeSlant=-0.5]{Georgia Italic} hello?
\end{document}
```

I'm not sure if you'd call the output attractive, exactly:

[image: backwards slanting italics]

Comment: I love it! the text looks surprised! as if it didn't expect to see me.

Answer (score 10):

Here is *fake slant* in pdfTeX. I use CMU10 (an upright italic font in Computer Modern) here:

```
\documentclass{article}

% redefine font mapping with fake slant
\pdfmapline{cmu10 CMU10 " -0.2 SlantFont " <cmu10.pfb} 

\begin{document}
\usefont{OT1}{cmr}{m}{ui}
\Huge Slant?
\end{document}
```

It also works for LuaTeX.

[image]

---

And this version for DVIPDFMx:

```
\documentclass{article}

% redefine font mapping with fake slant
\special{pdf:mapline cmu10 -r -s -0.167} 

\begin{document}
\usefont{OT1}{cmr}{m}{ui}
\Huge Slant?
\end{document}
```

It also works for XeTeX.

Comment: This is the way we add font mapping of Chinese fonts in `zhwinfonts.tex` of zhmetrics package.

Answer (score 4):

Computer Modern Funny (`cmfr` family) is one of this kind of font. cf:

http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/cmfunny/

[image]