# rotate entire font family

Tags: fonts

`PelicanStd` font looks like a slanted font like italic shape and no roman family available for this font. As per `AdobeInDesign` words, "`can apply negative slant of -11 to make it appears as roman`", how can we give this in TeX?

I am using MikTeX2.9 and Windows OS...

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11049/35864

Comment: @moewe Thanks, and this is good that this was possible in PDFLaTeX, but my requirement is to fix in LaTeX - MikTeX v2.9

Answer (score 5):

Compiling with `xelatex` you you can use the `fontspec` options `FakeSlant` and `FakeBold` (`lualatex` does not support `FakeBold`) to do this.

The quality of output is not good though and I wouldn't really recommend doing this to a font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\pelicanstd{Pelican Std}[%
  UprightFeatures={FakeSlant=-0.2},
  ItalicFont=Pelican Std,
  BoldFont=Pelican Std,
  BoldFeatures={FakeSlant=-0.2, FakeBold=1.5},
  BoldItalicFont=Pelican Std,
  BoldItalicFeatures={FakeBold=1.5},
]
\begin{document}
\pelicanstd
Pelican Std Fake Upright

\itshape Pelican Std

\bfseries Pelican Std Fake Bold

\upshape Pelican Std Fake Bold Fake Upright
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks, I too understand this requirement possible in XeLaTeX, but I should get this by using LaTeX - MikTeX V2.9...